# Length between two dates in a time series in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series composed of weekdays with anomalous/unpredictable holidays.  On any given day, I want to know the length/number of rows to a date specified under column 'date1'.  See below.

[image]

`len(df.loc['2019-10-18':'2019-11-15'])`  returns the correct answer

I am trying to create a column 'shift' that will calculate the above.

Both DatetimeIndex and the 'date1' are dtype 'datetime64[ns]'

`df['shift']=len(df.loc[df.index : df['date1']])` clearly doesn't work but might there be a solution that does?

Comment: How looks `shift` column?

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thank you jezrael but your suggestion returns the number of calendar days (28).  I need the number of rows (21).

Comment: So need `print (len(df.index))` ?

Comment: Sorry, not understand shifting here, `df['shift']=len(df.loc[df.index : df['date1']])`. So it is reason why ask for see how looks final column, all data are `22` ?

Comment: All dates are not 22 days.  The actual dates are irregular.  Which is why I need to count the rows between the two dates.

Comment: Sorry, not understand. Why cannot add final dataframe to question?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
df['len'] = (df.index - df['date1']).dt.days
```